# Decrypt dnn password for outside app- Error Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat'

Tags: asp.net, encryption, dotnetnuke

I'm using DNN database outside of the application to log persons into a new system; however I'm not what key they used to encrypt the password. All I see is the password format which is 2; that indicates that the password was encrypted using tripleDES. But I'm not sure where to go from there. I'm not interested in decrypting the user password because I know that's a security risk. Just want to match their passwords and log them into the new system. In my research I came across something like this include the Microsoft Membership Component in your app and use the same machineKey. How would I attempt that? I've tried this

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(txtUserName.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            // Log the user into the site
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtUserName.Text, RememberMe.Checked);
        }
        // If we reach here, the user's credentials were invalid
        lblError.Visible = true;
```

but it gives me this error message Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_Membership_GetPasswordWithFormat'; and I've already added the connection string in web.config

Comment: You won't be able to do this with SQL you'll need to use the MachineKey settings from the web.config and .NET to work with the passwords, that being said I don't think you'll be able to decrypt them directly.

Comment: I have the machine key i don't want to decrypt the password directly but to match

Comment: @ChrisHammond; is there a way I could achieve this.

Comment: Why not try login with user, if login success mean password is match.

Comment: But wouldn't that be a security risk @erw13n

Comment: @erw13n; what two users have the same username